# Why can't diskpart clean my disk?

Tags: windows-server-2012, partition

I have a Hyper-V Core Server 2012 R2 with the following disks:

```
Disk 0: SSD    C:\SSD (mount point to Disk 1)
Disk 1: HDD    C:\    (boot drive)
Disk 2: RAID-5        (not mounted)
Disk 3: RAID-0        (not mounted)
```

I want to clean disk 2 and create a new partition. I did the following:

```
C:\Users\mark>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 6.3.9600

Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: LITHIUM

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          111 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online          232 GB      0 B
  Disk 2    Online           10 TB  1936 GB
  Disk 3    Online         3724 GB      0 B        *

DISKPART> sel disk 2

Disk 2 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> clean

Virtual Disk Service error:
Clean is not allowed on the disk containing the current boot,
system, pagefile, crashdump or hibernation volume.


DISKPART>
```

I don't understand the error I'm getting. How can I tell for sure which disk I have booted from? Here's disk management if that helps:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the screenshot that the second partition of Disk 2 is marked 'System', and that's what the error message tells you about.

It seems to me your Windows Boot Manager and the BCD store is on that partition, you need to move it.

This blog post may help: [Switching my Windows 7 Boot Disk...](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchingMyWindows7BootDiskFromDToCWithBCDBootRatherThanBCDEdit.aspx)

Comment: Even though my server booted from DISK 1, in the BIOS it was set to boot from DISK 2, so put some system files there for some reason. All fixed now.